# it is not saving without an image

Tags: c#

i need to save this record without an image if its necessary.

this is my code i have used the if statement too:

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string commandText = "INSERT INTO Stock_Jewelry VALUES(@Stock_Type,@stock_no,@Quantity,@image)";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);

            command.Parameters.Add("@Stock_Type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters["@Stock_Type"].Value = Stock_Type.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@stock_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            command.Parameters["@stock_no"].Value = txt_stock_no.Text;

            command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = txt_qty.Text;

            if(pb1 != null) { 
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", pic);
            }
            else {
                pb1 = null;
            }

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("You've inserted successfully!", "Successful Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Hide();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Edit from comment:

> i can save with an image if i save without an image it says: `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: allow NULL for the image column in the database .... and add a NULL as param for the image

Comment: You need to make image column Nullable for this to work.

Comment: "it is not saving" is not a very helpful error description. Please paste the error you get into your question.

Comment: i can save with an image if i save without an image it says: object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: check `conn` for null - thats the only thing in this code that I see that could also be null

Comment: there is no conn = null;

Comment: SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        public S_Jewelry()
        {
            try
            {

                DB_CONNECTION dbObj = new DB_CONNECTION();
                conn = dbObj.getConnection();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't Open Connection!! " + ex);
            }
            InitializeComponent();


        }

Comment: i have mentioned:         SqlConnection conn;

Comment: You do not supply any connection string to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx - and yours looks weird. Why is the class spelled DB_CONNECTION() - allcaps?  Look up and try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185474/c-sharp-retrieving-correct-dbconnection-object-by-connection-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image column allows for `null` values, change to

```
if(pb1 != null) 
{ 
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    pb1.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", pic);
}
else 
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null); 
    // edit: replaced incorreect DBNull.Value due to comment by Heinzi
}
```

[System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary.Null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.null(v=vs.110).aspx)

Currently you are not providing enough parameters to your Sql if `pb1 is null`. When constructing the Sql it tries to access the SqlParameterCollection attached to your SqlCommand instance. Does not find anything for `@image` as given in the SqlCommand - hence the error.

Comment: If the image column is a `varbinary` column (which it should be), you can't use AddWithValue with DBNull.Value, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18170985/87698

Comment: i tried the code as to the answer still it didnt work

Comment: my table column is : Image.

Comment: sir mine is not a varbinary, it is an image. do you thing varbinary is better than image.

Comment: @mmsmms Your **database type** for your column _Image_ is an byte-array. Your code takes the `Image`type and saves its datastream into a `byte[]` which is then appended to your SQL as parameter `'@image'`to be stored. See [ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql) - image is just a byte[]

Comment: thank you for the code and your time sir.. i tried but still the same error..object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @mmsmms: Then you should follow the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/87698

Comment: Where did i go wrong can you please point it out. i hope i have the correct validation.

Comment: i dont know where else to mention null;

Comment: please help me out.